# Why firebase onAuthStateChanged always return a null value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import firebaseConfig from '../../FirebaseConfig';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const AuthChange = () => {
    const [UserInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            console.log('AuthChanged', user)
        if (user) {
            const information = {name: user.displayName}
            setUserInfo(information);
        } else {
            setUserInfo(null);
        }
    });
    }, [])
    return UserInfo;
}

export default AuthChange;
```

The output is

> Authentication.js:14 AuthChanged null

.
The output is always null, whether the user is signed in or not. How can I solve It?

Comment: Please, attach your sign in logic.

Comment: Everything works fine like signup and sign in. Usar was found for a few moments. When the page reloads, the value moves to null.

Comment: Which auth method are you using? Who reloads the page?

Comment: The auth method is email and password. When user successfully sign in then window.location.pathname = '/something' this system reload the page.